# Wind turbine: Back-to-back converter DC link

Tags: power-electronics, windturbine, renewable-energy

In the Type 4 topology of wind turbine generator, we use a back-to back ac/dc/ac converter in PMSG based wind turbine. Why do we need a dc link? Why cannot we simply use a cyclo-inverter instead of back-to-back converter that would also avoid the intermediate dc stage.

Comment: You **can** use a cyclo converter but, they are notoriously difficult to design, are not likely to be as efficient and, are likely to produce severe distortion and EMI on the output waveforms. Please also provide a link for "type 4 topology".

Comment: I meant type-4 wind turbine generators that employ back-to-back converters

Comment: @Saj, Andy's point was Type 4 of whose list of wind turbine generator types? Post a link in the question - not in the comments - to the list.